# Stop a network drive from automatically mapping

Tags: windows, mount, network-shares, login

I have a network drive that I originally set to automatically connect on login.  However, now I need it to stop doing that.  Even if I manually un-mount it as soon as I log back on it is back.

To mount the drives all I did was right click on My Computer and choose mount a network drive.  Once I entered the path information I checked reconnect after login.  Now it reconnects every time I log in.

I have multiple drives that I auto mount in this manner and I need to prevent just one of them from mounting on boot.

Comment: What method are you using to un-mount it?

Comment: right click and choose unmount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you unmounting?  Have you tried simply:

```
net use /d z:
```

Answer (score 3):

From [How to connect and disconnect a network drive in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308582):

**Disconnect from a mapped network drive**

1. Double-click `My Computer`.
2. Right-click the icon for the mapped drive.
3. Click Disconnect.

If it still returns, do :

> net use /persistent:no

and then reboot. When you now log in, all of your mapped drives should be gone and you can
remap the ones you need.

Comment: How do I prevent this from stopping the rest of my drives from auto-mounting?

Comment: No, you can do this selectively as far as I know, just specify the drive letter, like you would for mounting/mapping in the first place, so: net use x: \\server\path /persistent:no will map this just once and not persist, then net use x: /del will get rid of that drive alone (you may have to do steps 2, 1, 2 since you already have it mapped)

Answer (score 1):

Remount the drive as before, but leave the "[] Reconnect at logon" box UNCHECKED.  It will give a warning, but replace it anyway.  On the next logon, it will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have it mounting from a batch in startup? When you map it do you add `/persistent:no` at the end?

Comment: no I just mounted it by right clicking on my computer and told it to mount on login

Answer (score 0):

How did you set it to Automatically logon?  Was it a script?  If so, delete / amend the script.

Another alternative would be to create a script which removednetworkdrive.  This is an extension of Sean's idea.

Comment: no script, just right click on my computer and frollow the mount network drive wizard.  there is an option to mount on login that I chose.

Comment: Could it be as simple as unchecking 'Reconnect at logon'